How does netcat-openbsd work with UDP?
On a Ubuntu system I have the netcat(-openbsd) package installed, the one that, when run with no parameters, prints:
This is nc from the netcat-openbsd package. An alternative nc is available
in the netcat-traditional package.
usage: nc [-46bCDdhjklnrStUuvZz] [-I length] [-i interval] [-O length]
          [-P proxy_username] [-p source_port] [-q seconds] [-s source]
          [-T toskeyword] [-V rtable] [-w timeout] [-X proxy_protocol]
          [-x proxy_address[:port]] [destination] [port]


I run this command, which I think listens on a UDP port:
nc -v -u -l -k 1234

Then in another terminal I run this to talk to the listener:
nc -v -u 127.0.0.1 1234

But this behaves very different than I expect:

When I run the second command (sender), the first one (listener) starts printing "X" characters, one per seconds, 5 times. Only then the sender reports a successful connection. (How does it even know with UDP?)



If I omit the -v parameter on the sender side, which I thought only sets the logging verbosity, then the "X" characters are not printed on the listener side and instead the connection is established immediately.

Despite giving the -k parameter on the listener side, once I make a connection to the listener, the listener seems to be "used up". If I kill (Ctrl+C) the sender and start it again, any data sent is lost (does not appear on the listener side).


What am I missing? How do I correctly listen on a UDP port?
Edit: I found a way that works well (socat -u UDP-RECV:1234 STDOUT) but I'm keeping this question open because I'm still interested in an explanation.

Those X's are sent by the udptest() that nc does when the -z or -v flag is passed so as to be able to report that "successful connection"¹.
As UDP is not connection oriented, the only way to "tell" that there's someone on the other side is to send a packet (even several in case of unreliable path) and check if it's rejected (typically via ICMP packets).
So it should rather say "packets not rejected" than "connection succeeded" here. That "test" is quite intrusive as it ends up sending actual data² and is not reliable as packets could also be simply dropped by some firewall along the way, in which case you wouldn't be receiving ICMP rejections either.
As to your issue with packets not received from a second sender invocation, I cannot reproduce here with version 1.226-1.1 of the netcat-openbsd package on Debian trixie GNU/Linux amd64.
In any case, I would also use socat here.

¹ since version 1.223 (from OpenBSD 7.3) it doesn't do it for -v when stdin is not a tty device. See also related Debian bug; so running the client as cat|nc -vu 127.1 1234 would avoid those Xs with those newer versions; that also suppresses that connection succeeded message and in effect is equivalent to removing -v as it doesn't look like there's any other verbose message that nc may print in UDP client mode.
² It's possible to send a UDP packet with no payload, but not with the regular socket API. You'll see nmap can do it for its -sU UDP scan (and in the absence of rejection reports open|filtered, not successful connection), but only if run as root using the AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW interface and constructing the packets by hand. In that case though, with nc as the receiving end, sending that empty packet causes nc's recv() to return with 0 length which is taken as EOF but apparently not properly. My version of nc enters some form of infinite loop where it tries to call shutdown(SHUT_RD) but then carries on poll()ling + read()ing  input on the socket fd which keeps returning 0/EOF.
